# Why am I only seeing vertices in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to messily get rid of parts of my rough sculpt, but when I enter edit mode, I only see the object's vertices.

Here's what it looks like in object mode:

[image: The sculpted character in object mode.]

And here's what it looks like in edit mode:

[image: The sculpted character in edit mode.]

What's causing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you upload a file?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Fixed it! Apparently all I had to do was show hidden with <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> I'm not sure how exactly I managed to hide only faces in edit mode, but I've resolved the issue regardless.